Disable Pop-up "WebView Stop On Load" for Outlook Add-In
I am hosting an Outlook add-in, and the users are prompted with this pop-up when starting the add-in.
Outlook Addin Popup: "Webview Stop on Load: To debug the webview, attach VS Code to the webview instance using the Microsoft Debugger for Edge extension, and click OK to continue. To prevent this dialog from appearing in the future, click Cancel."
This is quite annoying, and therefore, I want to somehow prevent the pop-up from showing.
We are hosting the add-in by hosting the manifest.xml as well as the HTML, CSS and JS file.
Does anyone have an idea how to prevent this pop-up from showing?
Sidenodes:
I have read that one should start the add-in with office-addin-debugging and --no-debug, but as we are only hosting the files, this does not apply to us.
Perhaps, there is some option in the manifest.xml to be set, a response header that we should include or remove when sending the files or removing/adding additional info to our minified versions of the hosted files.

I encountered this issue with a PowerPoint add-in as well. The pop-up persisted even after I served the plugin manifest file. I resolved this by rebuilding the add-in using a production build and updating the version number in the manifest file.
After reinstalling the add-in in the Office application (PowerPoint) by refreshing the Add-ins page, I was able to update the plugin, and the pop-up dialog disappeared. I believe the issue occurs because the Office application saves a debug flag during development, and updating the "version" of the plugin allows it to run without debug mode.
